# Invalid response from .well-known/acme-challenge/<token> : 404 + nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, certbot

I have seen these questions ([^](https://serverfault.com/q/1060073/261596),[^](https://serverfault.com/q/926641/261596),[^](https://serverfault.com/q/1093830/261596),[^](https://serverfault.com/q/1110583/261596)), but unfortunately none of them could solve my problem.

I'm trying to use certbot to obtain an SSL certificate for one of my subdomains. However, the challenges fails when testing .well-known/acme-challenges/. The web server (nginx) returns 404. The precise error is:

```
Waiting for verification...                                                                      
Challenge failed for domain api.example.com                                                        
http-01 challenge for api.example.com             
                        
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: manual). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:                          
  Domain: api.example.com                         
  Type:   unauthorized  
  Detail: 139.x.x.x: Invalid response from http://api.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/7AujpY6MnpBkHAmVihpVSQXcEMYuMZFHjywSsAICtvQ: 404                                                 

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the manually created challenge files. Ensure that you created these in the correct location.    
                                                                                                 
Cleaning up challenges  
Some challenges have failed.
```

I even ran the below command manually from a separate system to get the certificate:

```
certbot -v certonly --manual --dry-run -d api.example.com
```

However, I got the same error again. I created the file according to the instructions in the corresponding folder (/var/www/certbot/) and copied its contents. I even gave 777 permission to the file and certbot folder and restarted the web server, but it still didn't work.

```
Create a file containing just this data:                                                         

7AujpY6MnpBkHAmVihpVSQXcEMYuMZFHjywSsAICtvQ.HQdAzFVYjmgUdQRvdJTBMm2eC2ZLOw-G-4TZr6JB0ak                                                          
And make it available on your web server at this URL:                                            
                        
http://api.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/7AujpY6MnpBkHAmVihpVSQXcEMYuMZFHjywSsAICtvQ
```

It seems that there is no access to the `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` at all. Even if I create a normal HTML file in the `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`, there is still no access to it.

I do this for the domain itself (`http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/`), for which the certificate has already been received, I still do not have access to the `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`.

My `nginx.conf` is as follows:

```
worker_processes auto;

events{
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  client_max_body_size 15M;
  include fastcgi.conf;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types
          text/css
          text/xml
          text/plain
          text/javascript
          application/javascript
          application/json
          application/x-javascript
          application/xml
          application/xml+rss
          application/xhtml+xml
          application/x-font-ttf
          application/x-font-opentype
          font/opentype
          application/vnd.ms-fontobject
          image/svg+xml
          image/x-icon
          application/rss+xml
          application/atom_xml;

  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=website:100m max_size=1024m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
  proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
  proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=30r/m;

  server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/certbot/;
    }

    location /{
      return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    location /{
      access_log /var/log/nginx/website_access_log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/website_error_log;
      limit_req zone=mylimit burst=5 nodelay;

      proxy_pass 'http://website/';
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
      expires 30d;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_cache website;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
      proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;

      proxy_cache_min_uses 3;

      proxy_cache_revalidate on;
      proxy_cache_background_update on;
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

      add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
      add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
      add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
      add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
      add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://cloud.domain.co/images/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com";
     # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
      add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()";

      #include http-headers.conf;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/certbot/;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/certbot/;
    }

    location / {
      return 301 https://api.example.com$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access_log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error_log;

      proxy_pass 'http://api:8090/';
      proxy_redirect off;
      
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
      add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://cloud.domain.co/images/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com";

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/certbot/;
    }
    # include http-headers.conf; 
    # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The URL `http://api.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/7AujpY6MnpBkHAmVihpVSQXcEMYuMZFHjywSsAICtvQ` should be located at `/var/www/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge/7AujpY6MnpBkHAmVihpVSQXcEMYuMZFHjywSsAICtvQ` - are you including the other two subdirectories?

Comment: No, I'll check it.

Comment: @RichardSmith, you're life saver, that's exactly my answer. please give that as an answer to accept. I thought that since `location/ .well-known/acme-challange/` came in the nginx.conf they were bound to the `var/www/certbot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certbot uses the URL `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...` to find its challenge/response file.

Nginx uses the [`root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) to convert the URL into a file name by concatenating the `root` value with the ["path" component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) of the URL.

Given the `location` block:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/certbot;
}
```

The URL `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/foo`, would expect to find the file `foo` in the directory:

```
/var/www/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge
```

You could invoke `certbot` with the `-w` command line option to specify the same path for the challenge/response file. For example:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot -d api.example.com
```